# How to resolve Cross-Origin Request Blocked issue?

Tags: jquery, spring, cors, restful-url

When am running this script its giving the error as Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://api.learnsocial.com/learnsocial/ad-placeholder?ref=EG0tF4__&aid=2. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).Can any one help me to resolve this problem.

```
<script > $(function() {
                    var adAPI = "http://api.learnsocial.com/learnsocial/ad-placeholder?ref=EG0tF4__&aid=2";
                     $.support.cors = true;     
                    $.getJSON(adAPI).done(function(data) {
                        var adt, src, lurl, h, w;
                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                            if (key === "at") {
                                adt = value;
                            } else if (key === "lu") {
                                lurl = value;
                            } else if (key === "ip") {
                                src = value;
                            } else if (key === "iw") {
                                w = value;
                            } else if (key === "ih") {
                                h = value;
                            }
                        });
                        document.write("<a href=" + lurl + " target='\_blank\'><img src=" + src + " width=" + w + " height=" + h + " alt=" + adt + " border='\0\' ></a>");
                    }).fail(function(d) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(d));
                });
                });</script>
```

Comment: CORS is the default functionality of browser.  the API at `http://api.learnsocial.com` has to enable CORS.

Comment: tnx and can you please help me how to enable cors .?

Comment: we have to enable  cors in tomcat ?

Comment: Is this `http://api.learnsocial.com` site yours ?. You can enable only if it is yours. And you said Tomcat. It means you are using Java . what is the name of the framework you are using?

Comment: yes santosh this is our domain only and we are using spring frame work

Comment: I didnt work on SPRING. so check these links      https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework  ,   https://dzone.com/articles/cors-support-spring-framework

Comment: i am using spring framework 3.0 the @RestController and crossorigin annotation classes are not found error coming